# Не могу понять как подключить библиотеку в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Хочу подключить библиотеку/  https://github.com/adblockplus/libadblockplus-android   Сделала по инструкции, прописала в  Gradle. Потом добавила в фрамент WebView

Это файл фрамента WebView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


<org.adblockplus.libadblockplus.android.webview.AdblockWebView
    android:id="@+id/main_webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    

    <WebView
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:id="@+id/webView_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:background="@drawable/loading_bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Loading"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressfb">
    </ProgressBar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/noConnectionLogo"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="240dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image"
            android:src="@drawable/no_internet" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNoConnection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/noConnectionLogo"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="No Internet Connection"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="26sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRetry"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtNoConnection"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:text="Retry"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Вы подключили, так как в репозитории?

Comment: Да, но происходит ошибка

Comment: Вернее подключила в грабле и лейаут, а в активити изминений не делала. Насколько я поняла так надо делать